# How to display those Unicode symbols of legacy computing?

Tags: unicode, terminal, fonts, symbols, legacy

I can print Unicode symbols like this in shell:

```
echo -e "\U0001f50c"
```

But I had no luck with those symbols in this chart:
https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1FB00.pdf

```
for example:
echo -e "\U1FBF0"
```

Any tricks to get this displayed properly (which should be an LED-style numerical zero)?

Comment: That *is* the character, the font just doesn't support the glyph so a generic replacement glyph is shown.

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/symbols_for_legacy_computing/fontsupport.htm

Comment: installed lastresort and it did not help. I suspect that it has to do with font linking, fallback, etc, as referenced below.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the font because without font support how can you render the text?
There are very few fonts that support [U+1FBF0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1fbf0/fontsupport.htm) so most systems can't show it properly. Try installing the font first

And then if you're using a different font for the terminal the in also depends on the [font linking, font fallback, font substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology) capabilities of the font renderer. If the renderer can't fallback to the font that contains that characters then you won't get the correct output either

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about getting fonts into terminal, but pretty sure that UNSCII font represents the range you are looking at

http://viznut.fi/unscii/